# How to find total counts of a double quotes(") in a row from csv file in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I need to find the doubt quotes(") row wise row using pyspark and filter records where double quotos(") counts has more than 22 using pyspark dataframe.

**Example of 1 row data in csv file which has 23 quotes instead of 22 double quotes**

```
"44","F.","Anu","","","Roma|Roma “La Sapienza","Roma "La Sapienza, Italy","1","37277552900,Aielli,L.","2008 Record",""
```

Answer (score 0):

## read file as text format

df_pubs = spark.read.load("filename.tsv",format="text", header="true")

#split the string based on double quotes (") values.
df2 = df_pubs.withColumn('count', F.size(F.split('value', '"')))